# in java using asterisk and question marks to match the name of a file

Tags: java, file-io

I want to write in java something like this:

```
public class MyMatcher 
{
   public static boolean isMatching(String filename, String param) { 
      ...
   }
}
```

filename would be the name of a file without the directory 
(e.g.: readme.txt, shares.csv, a nice song.mp3, ...)

param would be something like "*.mp3" to say all of the files ending with .mp3 and so on.

Note: param is not regular expression statement is more like the usual way of searching files like on textpad or eclipse or even the dos dir.

Can somebody suggest either how to do this or if there is some opensource library to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/) has a [WilcardFileFilter](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.3.2/org/apache/commons/io/filefilter/WildcardFileFilter.html):

> The wildcard matcher uses the characters '?' and '*' to represent a single or multiple wildcard characters.

Example from the javadoc:

```
File dir = new File(".");
FileFilter fileFilter = new WildcardFileFilter("*test*.java~*~");
File[] files = dir.listFiles(fileFilter);
for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
  System.out.println(files[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
String pattern = param.replaceAll ("\\*", ".*").replaceAll ("\\?", ".");
return filename.matches (pattern);
```

Comment: Won't work as expected in case the string being matched is already a regex or contains regex' special symbols. Example: "my.*.mp3" will match not only "my.somefile.mp3", but also "myxsomefile.mp3" and "myxsomefilexmp3".

Comment: Yes. If you have such cases, a more sophisticated handling will be neccessary.